# Add offset to pointer with a macro (GCC)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, offset

There is a similar question here [Portable and safe way to add byte offset to any pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934111/portable-and-safe-way-to-add-byte-offset-to-any-pointer)

but all answers are starting with **ptr = (SomeType*)...** which means that I have to
know the type of the pointer, while I want to use this macro:

```
#define ptradd(ptr, delta) (size_t) ptr = (size_t) ptr + (size_t) delta
ptradd(prect, offset);
```

it works under VC, but fails under GCC with the error
**lvalue required as left operand of assignment**.

How can I make it work under GCC?

Comment: `#define ptradd(ptr, delta) ptr = ((void*)((char*)ptr + delta))`? Note that it is UB if the alignment requirements are not met.

Comment: Writing such a macro is IMNSHO a mistake in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably *wrong* in defining such a `ptradd` macro. At least, it is very bad taste (and may become undefined behavior if the pointer or the delta are not well aligned, or if the actual macro arguments have side effects like `p++`).

You might perhaps try (and that should usually work on most C compilers, but I don't recommend writing that)

```
 #define ptradd(Ptr,Delta) do{\
   Ptr=(void*)((char*)(Ptr)+(Delta));}while(0)
```

but **I *really* dislike such unreadable macros**. And using them e.g. as `ptradd(p++,--i)` is a way for disaster.

You could even replace the `void*` with `typeof(*(Ptr))*` (this is GCC specific).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ptradd(ptr, delta) (ptr = (typeof(ptr)) ((size_t) ptr + (size_t) delta))

int main() {
    int a;
    int* b = &a;
    printf("b=%p\n", b);
    ptradd(b, 5);
    printf("b=%p\n", b);
}
```